# What are the correct permissions while "sys_open"ing a file?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I am trying to read the contents of a file using x86 assembly on Linux. The question is, what we should put into `edx` - the "permissions" register for sys_open.

I've used `open()` of C before; but there wasn't any "permissions" field. I am trying to read a file belongs to the same owner of the executable. The file's permissions are set to `0400` (`-r--------`). I've tried opening the file with `edx`: empty (0), `0666` and `0400`. All of them returns "-13" to `eax` which seems to be `EACCES`.

Sample code:

```
mov eax, 0x5;     //sys_open
push 0x6362612f //file name in hex, let's say "/abc"
mov ebx, esp;     //filename to ebx
xor ecx, ecx;     //O_RDONLY
mov edx, 0666o;   //permissions in octal for nasm
int 0x80;         //call it
```

What should `edx` to be to open a file, in general (or in this read-only case)? File's current permissions, an empty, an arbitrary?

Thanks!

Comment: [man 2 open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html): _"if neither O_CREAT nor O_TMPFILE is specified, then mode is ignored."_ Your problem is the `push file_name; mov ebx, esp`. You probably just want `mov ebx, file_name` but you have not provided a [MCVE].

Comment: `push "0xdeadbeef" ` If that's supposed to be an address, then don't quote it, and don't push it onto the stack. Just `mov` it into `ebx`. If that's supposed to be a string, then it's just wrong.

Comment: @Jester, thanks! So no permissions (a.k.a mode?) is needed at all to read-only? I've corrected my file name, it looks like the original now. It is the file name, not the address. I didn't want to define a string, instead just `push`ed. You can just paste these into a file and give to `nasm`; and then can see the `eax` with gdb.

Comment: You should not quote that. Also, it needs to be zero terminated.

Comment: Oh I forgot to remove, quotes don't exist in the code. Edited now. But I'll try null terminating then let you know.

Comment: Also make sure you are in 32 bit mode. `strace` is your friend.

Comment: Null termination doesn't affect anything. Yes, I'm in a 32 bit VM, and nasm input has `BITS 32` on top. Anyway, if the answer for my question is "mode is ignored", you can just post this as the answer so I can accept. My `EACCES` error seems to be so specific case of mine (in case of the `edx` is being ignored in `O_RDONLY`). Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your `/abc` wasn't null-terminated, the actual path would be `/abcXXXX...` until there was a `0` byte on the stack somewhere.  So you definitely want to `push ecx` after zeroing it, *before* pushing your string data.  Use `strace` to verify you're trying to open the right path.

Comment: Okay, got solved! The gdb was being run with another users permissions (which doesn't have permissions to read `/abc`) was causing the `EACCES`. Thanks for all the help. And @Jester, please do answer as "`edx` is being ignored".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[man 2 open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> if neither O_CREAT nor O_TMPFILE is specified, then mode is ignored.

As such it doesn't matter what you put in `edx` if you are opening an existing file for reading. The cause of your problems is something else.